# How I can put back button in first scene in Swift3.0?

Tags: swift, segue, back-button

I have two storyboard, SB_A,SB_B
So when I click the button at SB_A, it call

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "SB_B", bundle: nil)
        let nextView = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
        self.present(nextView!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

So I can see SB_B storyboard.
But I can't see the back button at first scene in SB_B
[image]

I want put back button at right scene and when I click that, back to SB_A storyboard.

How I can put back button at first scene in storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add these lines in SB_B viewdidload

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.leftNavigationItemAction(_:)))
}

@objc func leftNavigationItemAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) -> Void {
       _ = popOrDismissViewController(true)
}
```

try this one...

Comment: It occurs error,
Use of unresolved identifier 'popOrDismissViewController

Comment: remove the  popOrDismissViewController(true) and add this line 

self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: animated)

Comment: Your Welcome @PolarisNation

Answer (score 0):

No you can't use popviewonctroller or Dissmisviewcontroller to go back to previous storyboard's view controller you have to explicitly manage this back functionality to  get required functionality using push or present.

Comment: its only possible for same storyboard. changing a storyboard means you are changing your root controller then navigation hierarchy start from 0

Comment: 1. If you need to previous view controller instead of root view controller then you have to just to a popViewController.